# Can I Make a 14-3 cable Using Two 14-2s?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have an existing overhead light with a single light switch in my hallway.  I would like to add a second light switch, but I don't have any 14-3 cable.  Can I simply run two sets of 14-2 cable, and essentially ignore two of the six wires, or is that a terrible idea for reasons I don't understand?

Answer (score 4):

### Absolutely not.

All conductors in the circuit must travel together in the same cable (i.e. sheath or jacket) or raceway (i.e. conduit), NEC 300.3.  It would only be legal to use two sets of 14-2 *if they were in conduit*.

The reason for this is inductive heating occurring between the cables.

### Anyway, you need 14-4

You want to run three conductors: 2 messengers and a common.  That's the old way of doing it, and it's not legal anymore, because now you **must provide a true neutral wire** to each switch location.  That means 2 messengers, a common, *and a neutral*.  Get 14-4 or 14-2-2 from a *proper* electrical supply house, not the local bigbox.

### Beat the Christmas rush: go smart-switch

The reason for mandatory neutral is the smart-switch revolution (or to be more precise, the hokey, dangerous things people to do cheat a neutral when they don't find one). Instead of fighting, you can just go with it.

Use a smart switch at the primary location, then use a smart-switch remote at the secondary location.  Some of them communicate via wireless or power line signaling, so you don't even need a datacomm wire.  Simple 14-2 will do it.  Others are entirely battery operated and don't need any wires run at all.

Comment: In non-metallic sheathed  NM cable without conduit, I don't see how inductive heating would be an issue? Doesn't NEC 300.3(B) permit NM cables to be run separately? [NEC 300.3(B)(3) permits conductors in wiring methods with a nonmetallic (NM) sheath to be run in different cables. NEC 300.3(B) requires all circuit conductors of an individual circuit to be grouped to reduce inductive heating. This is not a problem with nonferrous wiring methods.](http://www.ecmag.com/section/codes-standards/using-two-cables-three-way-switch-mixing-plastic-and-metal-and-more)

Comment: @Johnny I think that article is wrong.  He's looking at 300.3B3 which gives an exception in 300.20B, but that calls for slotting metallic boxes typically in an industrial installation, not residential NM.  He also has a fundamental misunderstanding of how inductive heating occurs, thinking a nonferrous cable-raceway gives him a free pass.  Nope, and the informational note in 300.20B lays a hint there.